# export default react without mention redundant class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Dashboard = class Dashboard extends Component {
}

export default Dashboard
```

My code above is working but I feel guity mention 'Dashboard' for 3 times just to export one function. Is there anywhere to refactor it? What if I have different class but want to put in one file? as I know I can only do `export default` once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use default export once per file, like this:

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
}
```

Lets say you have more than one class in a file, and wants to export then use `named export`, like this:

```
export class Temp1 extends Component{
}
export class Temp2 extends Component{
}
```

To import this classes you need to write it like this:

```
import {Temp1, Temp2} from './temp';
```

Or you use `module.exports` to export many `classes/functions` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    Temp1: class extends Component{
    },
    Temp2: class extends Component{
    },
    Temp3: class extends Component{
    },
}
```

then use this it import it:

```
import {Temp1, Temp2} from './temp'
```

Check this article: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules